# What is the Difference between sklearn's make_blobs and a Multivariate Gaussian?

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, gaussian

Scikit-learn offers a utility [make_blobs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_blobs.html) that generates Gaussian blobs. Is there any advantage to using this over, say, scipy's [multivariate_normal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html#scipy.stats.multivariate_normal)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the documentation states Scikit-learn's `make_blobs` makes a number of isotropic Gaussian blobs. It can be viewed as a helper function, which saves you a little code. Nice if you have to demonstrate or test some clustering algorithm, so to avoid to much boilerplate code.

If you choose to use SciPy's `multivariate_normal` then can also control each cluster's covariance matrix. This could maybe be useful in some cases.